# Write to local machine registry in custom action (conditionally)

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac

Windows Installer has the smart feature to automatically decide whether to store registry values under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (using `Root="HKMU"` in WiX).

I need to write some complex registry keys during installation so I created a custom action for this. Depending on whether `ALLUSERS` is set or not `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` will be the location that is used by the custom action.

Unfortunately, I had to realize that even in an `ALLUSERS` installation the custom action does not have the required privilege to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` unless the installation is started as administrator. How do I get the custom action to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` but still keep the option of a per-user install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a custom action, you'll lose all the other smart features of Windows Installer such as ugprades, rollbacks, uninstalls and so on.

Instead,  put the registry values in their own component and put a condition on the component.  If the condition evaluates to true the component and it's associated registry resources will get installed.

Take a look at the [Privileged property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It sounds like what you are looking for to do your evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have now moved as much as possible into installer components that have conditions attached. This leaves me with a single requirement that's not feasible with Windows Installer so I have a custom action that will only be executed in a per-machine scenario.

Comment: Sometimes you don't _want_ to roll back a Registry entry, such as an indication that the software has already been installed before.